Icon in the selected value of the dropdown that is created with react-select
This is my first time using react-select and I have created the dropdown as below (I want this dropdown to be a re-usable component)
//import libraries
import React from 'react';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import classNames from 'classnames';

//import some svg icons using svgr
import Twitter from '@/assets/images/icon-twitter.svg';
import Linkedin from '@/assets/images/icon-linkedin.svg';
import Youtube from '@/assets/images/icon-youtube.svg';


export const PlatformDropdown = (listProps: any) => {
const options = [           
        { label: 'Twitter', value: 'Twitter', icon: <Twitter /> },
        { label: 'Linkedin', value: 'Linkedin', icon: <Linkedin /> },
        { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube', icon: <Youtube /> },
        { label: 'Facebook', value: 'Facebook', icon: <Facebook /> },       
    ];
const { Option } = components;

const IconOption = (props: any) => (
        <Option {...props}>
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                <div>{props.data.icon}</div>
                {props.data.label}
            </div>
        </Option>
    );

const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        listProps.setValue(e.value.toLowerCase());
    };

return (
        <Select
            options={options}
            components={{ Option: IconOption }}
            className="w-40 mx-auto"
            unstyled
            isClearable
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={listProps.value}
            classNames={{
                control: ({ isFocused }) => 'border border-gray-300 rounded-md',
                option: ({ isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) =>
                    classNames(
                        isSelected && 'text-purple [&_svg]:fill-purple',                        
                    )
            }}
        />
    );
};

The dropdown is working fine but as you can see in the first pic, the icons show on the list for selection. But the icon is NOT seen on the selected item. Can anyone help me fix this issue so that icon is seen on the selected value as well?


The solution for this issue can be found in here https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2553
